# How to write .prop in javascript or angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not great at jquery can someone convert that to javascript/angular?

```
$('#'+$(e.target).attr('for')).prop('checked',true);
```

That's the html

```
  <section class="numberOfPpl" [@fadeIn]="state">
              <span class="dropdown-el"  (click)="dropPerson($event)"  [ngClass]="{expanded: personChange }" >
                  <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="numberOfPeople" checked="checked"><label class="labelFirst2"  for="numberOfPeople">Number Of People</label>

                  <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="1-4" ><label for="1-4">1-4</label>

                  <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="4-8" ><label for="4-8">4-8</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="sortType" value="More"><label for="More">More</label>
                </span>
        </section>
```

I want just to change value/html output after clicking on for instance 1-4

Comment: This isn't a code writing service, no matter how trivial...

Comment: Please share the html

Comment: `prop()` is just a convenience method for accessing the `.property` on the Element.  If you have an element, you can access it's `.checked`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Document#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get based on the CSS selector. To get attribute value use [`Element#getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method. And finally, you can update the property simply by using [dot or bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```
document.querySelector('#' + e.target.getAttribute('for')).checked = true;
```

*FYI :* [Where `e` refers to the event object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Answer (score -3):

Pure Javascript, no jQuery

```
document.querySelector('#' + e.target + '[for]').checked = true;
```

Comment: Invalid selector.  `e.target` is an Element.  Also `[for]` looks for elements with that attribute.  It, in no way, selects the element the e.target `for` references